# prevent element from changing position of nearby elements

Tags: html, css

I have this design 
 [image]

when pressing the add or minus button the number decreases and increases and by doing so it will change the position of the buttons which is not desired. here is the code

```
                        <div  (click)="increment(item)">
                        <i class="icon-plus"></i>   
                        </div>
                        <label style="   font-size: 1.2em;  ">
                            8
                        </label>

                        <div  (click)="decrementQuantity(item)">
                         <i class="icon-delete"> </i>
                        </div>
```

I have tried to set a fixed width to the label but that make it overap the minus button, I have also tried to wrap them in a flex container and setting the position of them to space-between but that also doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Could you share full code with HTML friend :) and also javascript handler functions :)

Comment: *I have tried to set a fixed width to the label but that make it overap the minus button* --> set it big enough to cover the biggest number

Comment: How do you want to avoid that, given the user can press + 10000000 times?

Comment: I can, but it is really just JS since I'm not adding any extra classes to the elements, that is basically it. @ImranRafiqRather

Comment: one thing could be to place the buttons under the number, I guess

Comment: @DaisyLily: Temani Afif and Connexo have made a right argument. Numbers will eventually grow. Keep the big enough width to hold the maximum value

Comment: Could do that but would it look good? I don't think so. @TemaniAfif

Comment: this is the logical and *only* solution if you (1) don't want overlap and (2) you want all the number to fit and (3) fixed width label

Comment: I will just leave it as it is, thank you all for clarifying it to me. I really appreciate your efforts. @ImranRafiqRather

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number will grow eventually as the number grows.

You may try to increase width of `<label>`

**(OR)**

In case it is mandatory to have a fixed width for label, A fix would be to use a read only `<input/>` set fixed width to it and as the numbers grow they will still be there but only half visible as the number grows.